# getComponentAt() in MouseAdapter

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, runtime-error, mouse-listeners

Here I have the code:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
    public class MouseEvents extends MouseAdapter {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        JPanel selectedPanel = (JPanel) getComponentAt(e.getPoint()).getParent();
        }
}
```

It's probably a very simple reason, but I can't figure out why does `getComponentAt()` return the error `cannot find symbol`. Before, when I didn't have this problem it gave the error that `getComponentAt() could not be referenced in a static context` -- but how is it being referenced as static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't *have* a `getCompnentAt()` method in your code.

That's a method in the [`Component` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) (and of course all classes that inherit from it).

You need to retrieve the `Component` from your `MouseEvent`:

```
Component c = e.getComponent();
```